# Bootstrap: how to use inline radios for wide screen and stacked radios for small screen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 radio buttons. For wide screen (for example: PC) I want to show them in one line, for small screen (For example: Phone), I want to show them in a stack.

How can I do that? Below is my code that shows the radios in one line.

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="radio-list">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" /> AAA
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" /> BBB
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" /> CCC
            </label>        
         </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

## Code

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
    .radio-inline {
        display: block;
        min-height: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
    .radio-inline+.radio-inline, .checkbox-inline+.checkbox-inline {
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}
```

## Example

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KqBK/)

Resize the **result frame** to view the effect.